# Sort Arraylist of Objects by another array

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

Objects in `ArrayList<CustomObject>` `array A` are unsorted:

```
ID: [6, 3, 2, 5, 4, 1]
```

From another part of a program I received `array B`. Need to sort objects in `array A` by property `int ID` in the way `array B` is sorted:

```
[3, 6, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```

So `array A` should be finally sorted like:

```
[3, 6, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```

So the objects in `array A` are sorted by ID exactly like items in `array B` are.

What would be the best way to implement it?

Comment: What is benchmark ordering?

Comment: @cricket_007, the final look of the order I need to achieve

Comment: Are you trying to sort with respect to something? What is your comparison function? Your result is not ascending or descending, so it will be difficult to get what you are looking for.

Comment: @cricket_007, yeap, it's not just asc or desc or something... it's an array of identificators I received from another function and need to apply them to sort Objects in ArrayList. So this ArrayList is sorted by it's ID field in the way the array is set

Comment: Say I received an array of "Apple", "Orange" and "Banana" and put them in my bag in this order. But Mom came and said "Hey, you should put them like: "Orange" -> "Apple" -> "Banana".

Comment: I don't understand. 1) Your first array is "unsorted", not "randomly sorted" and 2) There is no obvious ordering at all to your second array. For example. `4 < 6`, and `6 > 5`. And in that example, lexicographical ordering would be "Apple", "Banana", "Orange". Sort those strings by length, and you get the first ordering...

Comment: ....no, that was just an example. Okay, the array A is unsorted. Then, I need to sort it in the way the array B looks like. So the objects in array A is sorted by ID exactly like items in array B are.

Comment: Maybe I should instead be asking why specifically do need an ordering like that? What is wrong with simply ascending or descending order?

Comment: Well, it's a user decision in one part of a program, I need to reference it in another, so I saved the order he selected and now need to order new things in the same way.

Comment: Just by looking at the array you can't know what kind of ordering it has.. Maybe each value refers to some other object and if you order those you get that array... But like cricket told you it seems like random... Try to look at the method or class that ordered array B if you can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
    List<CustomObject> a = Arrays.asList(
        new CustomObject(6),
        new CustomObject(3),
        new CustomObject(2),
        new CustomObject(5),
        new CustomObject(4),
        new CustomObject(1)
    );
    System.out.println(a);
    int[] b = {4, 6, 5, 3, 1, 2};
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; ++i)
        map.put(b[i], i);
    // for Java8
    // Collections.sort(a, (l, r) -> map.get(l.id) - map.get(r.id));
    Collections.sort(a, new Comparator<CustomObject>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(CustomObject l, CustomObject r) {
            return map.get(l.id) - map.get(r.id);
        }
    });
    System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: thanks, seems to be a solution. But could you please rework it without using lambdas? Android does not complie on Java 1.8, that's a pity cricket_007 removed my `Android` tags from the question

Comment: How does " (l, r) -> map.get(l.id) - map.get(r.id) " work??

Comment: @saka1029 wrong 2nd argument type. Found: ...CustomObject, required java.util.Comparator<? super java.lang.Integer> on `sort` function

Comment: Is 1st argument type ```List<CustomObject>```?

Comment: Finally worked exactly like was suggested, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

This may helpful to you :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<Integer, Integer> myMap = new HashMap();
    int arrayA[] = {6, 3, 2, 5, 4, 1};
    int arrayB[] = {3, 6, 4, 5, 1, 2};
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayA.length; i++) {
        if (myMap.containsKey(arrayA[i])) {
            int pValue = myMap.get(arrayA[i]);
            pValue++;
            myMap.put(arrayA[i], pValue);
        } else if (!myMap.containsKey(arrayA[i])) {
            myMap.put(arrayA[i], 1);
        }
    }
    int l = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayB.length; i++) {
        if (myMap.containsKey(arrayB[i])) {
            int pValue = myMap.get(arrayB[i]);
            for (int k = 0; k < pValue; k++) {
                arrayA[l++] = arrayB[i];
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayA));

}
```

Out-put :

```
[3, 6, 4, 5, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Duplicate `contains` on the same element is needlessly costly.

Answer (score 0):

Approach

1. First create a comparator object initialize it with the required
   arrayOrder
2. Call the Collection.sort with the comparator object

I understand that this could be an over kill for a simple solution mentioned above. but I have tried to exploit `Comparator` interface from the `java.utils`

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

class CustomerCompartor implements Comparator<Customer> {
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    ArrayList arrayOrder;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public CustomerCompartor(Integer[] arrayOrderInt) {
        this.arrayOrder = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(arrayOrderInt));

    }

    public int compare(Customer cust1, Customer cust2) {

        int cust1Order = this.arrayOrder.indexOf(cust1.getId());
        int cust2Order = this.arrayOrder.indexOf(cust2.getId());
        return cust1Order - cust2Order;
    }
}

class Customer {

    int id;

    public Customer(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public class ArrayOrder {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Customer> customerArray = new ArrayList<Customer>();

        customerArray.add(new Customer(1));
        customerArray.add(new Customer(2));
        customerArray.add(new Customer(3));
        customerArray.add(new Customer(4));
        customerArray.add(new Customer(5));
        customerArray.add(new Customer(6));

        for (Customer cust : customerArray) {
            System.out.println(cust.getId());
        }

        Integer[] arrayOrder = new Integer[] { 3, 6, 4, 5, 1, 2 };

        CustomerCompartor comparator = new CustomerCompartor(arrayOrder);
        Collections.sort(customerArray, comparator);

        for (Customer cust : customerArray) {
            System.out.println(cust.getId());
        }

    }
}
```